# Search a column of names in another data frame and get the result with data from other column combined

Tags: r, dataframe, left-join

I want to create a data frame based in two data frames distincts.

The first one has the name of journals ans its respective impact factor.
The second data frame has the names of the journals that I want to search.

df1:

```
Full Journal Title  Journal Impact Factor

CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS  223.679
Nature Reviews Materials    74.449
NEW ENGLAND JOURNAL OF MEDICINE 70.670
LANCET  59.102
NATURE REVIEWS DRUG DISCOVERY   57.618
CHEMICAL REVIEWS    54.301
Nature Energy   54.000
NATURE REVIEWS CANCER   51.848
JAMA-JOURNAL OF THE AMERICAN MEDICAL ASSOCIATION    51.273
NATURE REVIEWS IMMUNOLOGY   44.019
NATURE REVIEWS GENETICS 43.704
NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY   43.351
NATURE  43.070
and continues...

str(df1)
data.frame':    12541 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ my.journal: Factor w/ 11879 levels "","2D Materials",..: 4155 1872 8866 8999 8033 8861 2143 8841 8856 5795 ...
 $ jcr       : Factor w/ 4732 levels "","0.000","0.006",..: 4731 2905 4614 4613 4337 4336 4335 4334 4333 4332 ...
```

df2:

```
     my.journal
1                           Bioscience journal
2            Summa phytopathologica (impresso)
3            Summa phytopathologica (impresso)
4            Summa phytopathologica (impresso)
5  Australian journal of crop science (online)
6            Summa phytopathologica (impresso)
7                       Summa phytopathologica
8      Pesquisa agropecuaria tropical (online)
9      Crop breeding and applied biotechnology
10             Genetics and molecular research
11                    Tropical plant pathology
12             Genetics and molecular research
13     Perspectivas online: biológicas e saúde
14            Científica (jaboticabal. online)
15     Journal of plant physiology & pathology
16                    Tropical plant pathology
17           Summa phytopathologica (impresso)

> str(df2)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ my.journal: Factor w/ 11 levels "Australian journal of crop science (online)",..: 2 10 10 10 1 10 9 8 4 5 ...
```

I want another df (df3) where the journals in df2 where searched in df1 and if match give me something like this (Without the *NA*):

In *NA* place i want the Journal Impact Factor correspondet to the journal in my df2.

df3

```
journal                                     jcr   total
   <chr>                                       <fct> <int>
 1 Summa phytopathologica (impresso)           NA        5
 2 Genetics and molecular research             NA        2
 3 Tropical plant pathology                    NA        2
 4 Australian journal of crop science (online) NA        1
 5 Bioscience journal                          NA        1
 6 Científica (jaboticabal. online)            NA        1
 7 Crop breeding and applied biotechnology     NA        1
 8 Journal of plant physiology & pathology     NA        1
 9 Perspectivas online: biológicas e saúde     NA        1
10 Pesquisa agropecuaria tropical (online)     NA        1
11 Summa phytopathologica                      NA        1
```

I'm starting using R a few months and I don't know how to start to resolve this.

The two dataframes are in the link [df1 and df2](https://gofile.io/?c=SvgRvh)

Comment: Is `df2` a data frame? Or just a vector? You don't show any column names, which makes it look like it might be a vector. Look at `class(df2)` to tell.

Comment: Hi @Gregor it`s really a data frame. I edited at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**:

One solution would be to use `join` with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- read.table("df1.txt", skip = 1, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- read.table("df2.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Full.Journal.Title = toupper(Full.Journal.Title))

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(my.journal = toupper(my.journal))

df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("my.journal" = "Full.Journal.Title")) %>%
  group_by(my.journal, Journal.Impact.Factor) %>%
  summarize(total = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(total))

my.journal                                  Journal.Impact.Factor total
   <chr>                                       <chr>                 <int>
 1 SUMMA PHYTOPATHOLOGICA (IMPRESSO)           NA                        5
 2 GENETICS AND MOLECULAR RESEARCH             NA                        2
 3 TROPICAL PLANT PATHOLOGY                    1.254                     2
 4 AUSTRALIAN JOURNAL OF CROP SCIENCE (ONLINE) NA                        1
 5 BIOSCIENCE JOURNAL                          0.375                     1
 6 CIENTÃ­FICA (JABOTICABAL. ONLINE)            NA                        1
 7 CROP BREEDING AND APPLIED BIOTECHNOLOGY     1.026                     1
 8 JOURNAL OF PLANT PHYSIOLOGY & PATHOLOGY     NA                        1
 9 PERSPECTIVAS ONLINE: BIOLÃ³GICAS E SAÃºDE   NA                        1
10 PESQUISA AGROPECUARIA TROPICAL (ONLINE)     NA                        1
11 SUMMA PHYTOPATHOLOGICA                      NA                        1
```

A few things to note to make this work:

- Reading in `df1` the header appears to take up 2 rows, so skipped the first line (since this more closely matched your previous example)
- `read.table` includes `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if you do not want them as factors
- Some journal names are upper case, others lower case. The join is case-sensitive so included `toupper` to make everything upper case before the join (as an alternative, you can embed the `toupper` inside the `left_join` if you want to leave the original data frames untouched)

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: No warning if they are `character` to begin with, if imported with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` (my default) or if pre-corrected with `as.character`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for noticing - I inadvertently assumed they were factors...

Comment: Easy to do (and common) when the question doesn't have solid sample data.

Comment: It`s almost there,. Really the warning message appears. But when I changed to character other message appears: Error in UseMethod("right_join") : it could not be applied to a character class

Comment: Warning messages:
1: Column `Full Journal Title`/`Journal Impact Factor` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector 
2: Factor `Journal Impact Factor` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

Comment: @PedroHenrique to address this --- could you provide the structure of your data frames (e.g., `str(df1)`) and the code you are using so far? Please edit your question above and we can go from there...

Comment: Thanks @Ben I edited the questions and uploaded the files of the dataset

Comment: @PedroHenrique The impact factors are NA because it could not match any journals, as the join is case sensitive, and sometimes the names are in all caps. See above edits, it should work with your data files.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ben !!! You're genius... it was exactly what I've looking for. Thank you.